# NestJS - current auth user but not via decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, authentication, nestjs

I create belowed decorator to get current logged in to the system user,

```
export const CurrentUser = createParamDecorator(
    (data: unknown, ctx: ExecutionContext) => {
      const request = ctx.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      return request.user;
    },
  );
```

but I do not want to use this because i need to use in any of my controller
which is a bit troublesome for me because some functions are optional, i.e. both for the logged in user and the non logged in user,

so, how can I get current logged in user in my `service` in functions when i want to get current user instead of all via decorator in controller?

thanks for any help

Comment: Pass current use from Controller to Service via parameter.

Comment: @hoangdv do you read this topic? -> `but I do not want to use this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to make a custom provider and inject the request into it. Something like this

```js
{
  provider: 'CURRENT_USER',
  inject: [REQUEST],
  useFactory: (req: Request) => {
    return req.user;
  },
  scope: Scope.REQUEST,
}
```

(`REQUEST` is injected from `@nestjs/core`)

Then the user can be injected into the service with `@Inject('CURRENT_USER')`. Keep in mind, this will make the service `REQUEST` scoped, and by [scope hierarchy](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes#scope-hierarchy) it will make whatever you inject the service into `REQUEST` scoped.

### Edit 2/15/21

An example of this module could look something like this:

```js
@Module({
  providers: [{
    provider: 'CURRENT_USER',
    inject: [REQUEST],
    useFactory: (req: Request) => {
      return req.user;
    },
    scope: Scope.REQUEST,
  }],
  exports: ['CURRENT_USER'],
})
export class CurrentUserModule {}
```

And now in whatever module that has the service that needs the current user you do

```js
@Module({
  imports: [CurrentUserModule],
  providers: [ServiceThatNeedsUser],
})
export class ModuleThatNeedsUser {}
```

and in the service:

```js
@Injectable()
export class ServiceThatNeedsUser {
  constructor(@Inject('CURRENT_USER') private readonly user: UserType) {}

  // rest of class implementation
}
```

Comment: Where i need to use this? I do not know where to paste this code, into module?

Comment: If you need to use this provider in several services, I'd make a module that declares the provider in its metadata and exports it. Then you can import that module wherever that custom provider is needed

Comment: I try this, and i got an error: Argument of type '{ provider: string; inject: string[]; useFactory: (req: Request) => any; scope: Scope; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ModuleMetadata'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'provider' does not exist in type 'ModuleMetadata'. Did you mean to write 'providers'?ts(2345)

Comment: have you any solution?

Comment: I said to make a [custom provider](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers). Custom providers go in the `providers` array. I didn't say anything about adding that to the `imports`.

Comment: Ok, I do this, I'm inject this module in my constructor, but still my app is not running because i do not know how to import this module in to service module, can you show an bigger example?

Comment: @markWanka sample added. Very basic, but it should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I am using version 8 of nestjs and this approach runs before authguard so the req.user is undefined.